# Google Chrome block the SWF on FB TAB

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, flash

how can embedded the flash swf on the tab page in facebook?
always Google Chrome block the swf ?

could please give me a solution?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Did you use same the same protocol? Most of FB users is using SSL. Try  to embed via https.